# Problem with Nvidia GT 545 driver on a Dell XPS 8300

Tags: 11.10, nvidia

I'm having problems with the GPU on my new Dell XPS 8300.  After some problems installing Ubuntu 11.10 64bit (it kept failing after listing the "attached scsi removable disk"s) I realized it was the GPU stopping installation so I unplugged it and unused the onboard graphics and everything installed fine.

The GPU is Nvidia GT 545 1GB DDR5  I checked there was a linux driver before ordering that one and there is, not sure if the open source one covers this hardware and works well but I'm happy to use either.

When I plug in the GPU it stops the system booting (even if I'm not using it and have the monitor still plugged in to the motherboard VGA). Very early in the boot an error code comes up and the system seems frozen
udev sbin PCI. . .  [177]

I wondered if I should install the driver before connecting the GPU but when I try that it tells me there is no card installed and so I can't do that.

I'm fairly sure the GPU works as the system came with windows and I had a quick look at that to confirm it was annoying and I should wipe and install linux and the GPU worked fine there.

So I'm not sure how to even attempt to solve this and any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  <sup>[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1904230)</sup>:

> 1. Do a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 with Alternate CD, X64-bit (probably any dist of 11.10 will work).
> 2. Use another computer to download and burn SuperGrub2 iso.-image to a cd/dvd and boot with it (or create a bootable usb-stick with it).
> 3. Select the Third option: "Detect Grub .cfg" and boot with it (press Enter two times).
> 4. Wait 10 seconds and enter your full disc encryption key and press Enter, even if the screen still is black.
> 5. Wait 30 seconds and you'll have the 11.10 login menu with perfect drivers and hardware acceleration.
> 6. Use Software Center to install GNOME Shell.

I had the same problem with X64 and Nvidia graphic card, and finally got it to work with hardware acceleration and everything.